# How to unit test Python function that returns a relative path?

Tags: python, filepath, doctest

I wrote a Python function that produces a filepath for a dataset.  I'd like to include a doctest for the function.  However, since each machine will have a different relative filepath, I'm not sure how to write the test so that it will pass on any machine.

```
import os

def get_dataset_file_path(date, filename):
    """Produces a filepath for the dataset.

    :parameter date (string): The date folder name.  Ex: "2020-02-05"
    :parameter filename (string): The csv filename.
    :returns filepath (string): The filepath for the dataset.

    Example:

    project_root
    ├── README.md
    ├── data
    │   └── 2020-04-13
    │       ├── README.md
    │       ├── data_description.txt
    │       ├── test.csv
    │       └── train.csv
    ├── docs
    ├── requirements.yml
    └── results
        └── 2020-04-13
            └── runall.py

    The function is called from the 'runall.py' file.
    >>> get_data_file_path('2020-04-13', 'train.csv')
    '~/project_root/data/2020-04-13/train.csv'
    """

    basepath = os.path.abspath('')
    filepath = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(basepath, "..", "..")) + "/data/" + date + "/" + filename
    return filepath
```

Comment: There are different testing philosophies: this question is probably too general to be answered specifically. Do you want to test a specific thing that can be coded specifically?

Answer (score 1):

I would [mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) the `os.path.abspath`.

The specifics depend on your testing framework. I prefer `pytest` with `pytest-mock` and would write something like this:

```
def get_dataset_file_path(mocker):
    mocked_abspath = mocker.patch('os.path.abspath')
    mocked_abspath.return_value = '/project_root/'
    assert get_data_file_path('2020-04-13', 'train.csv') == '/project_root/data/2020-04-13/train.csv'
```